# Is there a way to ensure no items are repeated from a random list and output something if they all have been outputted?

Tags: python, random

I'm doing a song guessing game and all the songs are in a file and are randomly outputted after being processed to only show the first letter, however is there a way to ensure that no songs are repeated, due to it being random, and to make an end message if all of them have been outputted to the user. I couldn't really show the whole code or isolate the issue concisely so sorry for no examples, but I hope this is enough to go off. Feel free to ask any more questions! Thanks in advance

Comment: "I couldn't really show the whole code or isolate the issue concisely so sorry for no examples" you absolutely _could_ do that, you just gave up. It's perfectly possible to create an example where you pick from a list without replacement

Comment: You could use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to randomize the list of songs, then iterate through the shuffled list.

Comment: I did try, trust me. but trying to get it exact to the problem I am getting is proving more difficult than I expected, I am going to keep trying but for now, if anyone could help without then I would greatly appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick random unique items from a list you can use `random.sample(list, size)`. This returns a new list with all the unique elements.